# Multiplatform print service

Tags: java, c#, python, printing, mono

I'm developing an application that should communicate with a small server.
The server, when invoked, should prints on a phisical printer the data received by the application.

The server must be multiplatform (mac, windows).

I tryed with an c#-oriented solution (nancyfx + gtk#), but I cant figure out how to print on a phisical printer using mono.

I also tryed with Java (jersey + awt) but I'm using a POS printer (continuus rool) and java seems to be not ready for this.

I checked also Python, but I have not found anything interesting.

Can you help me please?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use cups as a subprocess?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/python-escpos/